# Pros of specifying type of event in function?, ActionScript 3

Tags: function, actionscript-3, events, parameters

When creating a `MouseEvent`-triggered `function`, you can write

```
public function Hover(e) {
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
public function Hover(e:MouseEvent):void {
  ...
}
```

What are the advantages of using the latter, more specific way of defining a `function`? Will this affect the garbage collector, or other less obvious things?

Comment: I can't help but feel like you are trying to find justification to use the former because it's less characters to type. If that's the case and you want to type less, use a proper development environment with code completion. Don't compromise on code quality (the latter code is strictly better) just to save a few keystrokes.

Comment: I certainly don't want to compromise on code quality.

What I wondered was how this might effect the program itself. For instance if you skip `:void` at the end. Could the garbage collector or general performance be affected by this in any way?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Declaring a function as **`void`** if it doesn't **return** any _data type_ is just correct "grammar" for C-like languages (C#, Java, AS3 etc). No issues should arise unless you try a `myVar = someFunctionResult();` when the function is set to `void`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying a type gives you type safety at compile time.
That leads to benefits like compile time errors (instead of runtime errors) and code completion in your development environment.

It also adds to the readability, because the type is clearly stated.